# Ошибки в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Вот такие ошибки выскакивают при попытке компиляции приложения. В нём нет никакого кода, кроме автоматически сгенерированного. С чем это может быть связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: File -- Project Structure -- `Use the embedded JDK`, установлена галочка?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" означает что приложение было скомпилировано на версии Java 8 и не будет работать на версиях ниже.

Зайдите в настройки и проверьте соответствуют ли JDK и Android SDK требованиям компилируемого проекта.

Comment: А остальные 75 ошибок?

Comment: Если версии несовместимы, то там может быть и сотни ошибок. В каждой строчке где найдётся несоответствие. Сначала установите правильное JDK.

Comment: Фактически вы используете API, которого у вас нет. Вызываете методы, которых у вас нет и пользуетесь классами которые ведут себя иным образом.

Comment: Отсюда и столько ошибок